# Sequence definition of limit - quantifier order

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

So the formal definition of a limit of a sequence An is:

∀{ε>0} ∃{N natural} ∀n>N {|An - L|< ε}

If we switched the order of the quantifiers around:

∃{N natural} ∀{ε>0} ∀n>N {|An - L|< ε}

Would that still implicate the sequence converges to L?

After all this means that such an N exists, and for every n after it the distance between the sequence and the limit is less than any given epsilon.
This is true because I don't need to pick a specific N at first I think.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

In general, if $\mid x-y \mid<\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon >0$, then $x=y$, since if $x\neq y$, then we would have $\mid x-y \mid = \varepsilon _0$ for some $\varepsilon _0>0$. But then since $\mid x-y \mid<\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon >0$, we have that $\mid x-y \mid < \varepsilon _0$, a contradiction.

Thus, if the second definition holds, then $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N$, $a_n=L$. This means that after a certain point the sequence would be $L$ constantly, so it would still converge to $L$.

But this isn't a valid definition for convergence, since, for example, the sequence $a_n=\frac 1n \rightarrow 0$, but there isn't an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N$, $a_n=0$.

Comment: But hold on :), choosing the N is dependent upon the other two quantifiers and the condition ∀{ε>0} ∀n>N {|An - L|< ε}. So even in the series 1/n, whichever N I choose, for the next n, if it is greater than N, the distance between the sequence and L will be less than that was for N. Maybe looking at it like ∣x−y∣=ε0 for the chosen N is misleading, because we're only choosing the N based on what happens after.

Comment: Oh wait, are you saying that there exists a natural number $N$ for every $\varepsilon >0$ such that for all $n>N$, $|A_n-L|<\varepsilon$? Because if so, that is equivalent to the actual definition. But it's not a great way to word it because it looks a lot like "there exists a natural number $N$ _such that_ for all $\varepsilon >0$ and for all $n>N$, $|A_n-L|<\varepsilon$". The last definition is wrong since it implies that $A_n=L$, which is not a valid definition for convergence.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't strike me as terribly wrong, but it doesn't seem right to me. Finding $N$ is dependent upon the $\varepsilon$ that you are given. If you are given $\varepsilon=1$ (for example) $then$ you can think about how to find your $N$ to work with that $\varepsilon$. But to talk about the existence of $N$ before introducing $\varepsilon$ just seems so backward. It's like playing hide and go seek, but you go looking for people before they have hidden.